# Excel Formula For Value Based On Another Cell's Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

1. I have an item (shoes)
2. I have a list of categories (sneakers, loafers)
3. I have a list of discounts based on categories above

How can the cell containing my item (shoes) have the right discount based on its category? sample table:

```
------------------------------
| item | category | discount |
------------------------------
| shoes| loafer   |    ?     |
------------------------------
```

Pseudocode for formula: if category cell equals loafer, make this cell's value equals 5.

Maybe I am going the wrong way about this but I simply cannot add discounts manually. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You most likely want the `VLOOKUP` function.

Comment: Build a cross-reference table containing the discounts; one of the entries would be [shoes] [loafers] [5] then use a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) to retrive the 5 where item is shoes and category is loafer. You won't actually be summing any more than a single entry but the SUMIFS is the most efficient method of retrieving a number for multiple criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list in some sheet of categories and discounts

e.g. in G3:H6 you could have

```
type    discount
loafer  5%
oxford  20%
sneaker 10%
```

Then if you have "loafer" in B2, you would put into B3...

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,G4:H6, 2,FALSE)
```